# Is there any error of my version of Limit of Composite Functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I've come up with this alternative and more general theorem about Limit of Composite Functions. I want to ask whether the statements are **all** correct, and if there is something can modify to be better?

PS: My definition of limits of functions requires the point discussing to be a cluster point of the domain, whereas the continuity of function at a point is just need the point to be in the domain(and the rest $\epsilon$-$\delta$ requirements).

**Theorem:**

Let $E,F\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, $g:E\to F$, $f:g(E)\to\mathbb{R}$, $L\in\mathbb{R}$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}g(x)=L$, then:

(1) If $\begin{cases}\exists\delta>0,\forall x\in(c-\delta,c+\delta)\cap E,g(x)\neq L\\\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\text{ exists}\end{cases}$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}(f\circ g)(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$.

(2)If $L\in g(E)$ and $f$ is continuous at $L$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to c}(f\circ g)(x)=f(L)$. (This term is not necessarily equals to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$)

Comment: I must be misunderstanding something since, imo, your last words are false: if $\;f\;$ is continuous at $\;L\;$ then $\; \lim\limits_{x\to L}f(x)=f(L)\;$ .

Comment: @DonAntonio $L$ may be an isolated point of the set $g(E)$. In this case, $f$ is trivially continuous at $L$ but may not have a limit. (i.e. $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$ does not exist.)

Comment: You wrote your definition of limit of function at some point requires that point to be a cluster one of the domain. In **my** definition of continuity the finite existence of the limit of that function at that point is necessary. You say *your* definition of continuity only requires the point to be in the domain "with the rest of $\;\epsilon-\delta\;$ , yet if we don't have some open neighborhood of that point where the function's defined how are we going to achieve that? Perhaps you should write down *explicitly* what your definition of continuity is.

Comment: It is the same as [this(page 17)](https://collineubanks.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/a-real-analysis-reference.pdf). Hence, from this definition, a function $f$ only defined on $\{1\}$ by $f(1)=100$ is continuous at $1$.

Comment: Well, that's the *usual* definition although it is not required the domain to be open. Anyway, **if** $\;\lim\limits_{x\to L}f(x)\;$ exists it is because $\;L\;$ is a cluster point of the domain of definition (two sided limit), **and then** if $\;f\;$ is continuous there then the limit equals $\;f(L)\;$ . In this case, it cannot be $\;L\;$ is an isolated point as then the limit, by what I read in that document (page 11), couldn't exist.

Comment: @DonAntonio I guess I have known what you mean. If I rephrase the last sentence more clearly as: "this term is not necessarily equals to $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$, since $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to L}f(x)$ may not exist." would you accept it?